# 101 SOQL Queries Limit Exception

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

Even when I think that I have bulkified my code, it is still throwing a *SOQL 101 Limit Exception* on the code below on Line 5 (For loop One). What I am doing Wrong?

UserIds is just a list of Oppportunties.OwnerIds

```
global static map<Id, Contact> getEmployeeInfos(list<Id> userIds)
{
       map<Id, Contact> employeeContacts = new map<Id, Contact>();

       for (Contact c : [SELECT Name, User__c, User__r.IsActive, LOB__c, Email, Phone,LOB__r.Short_Name__c, LOB__r.Name FROM Contact WHERE User__c IN :userIds])
       {
            employeeContacts.put(c.User__c, c);
       }

       return employeeContacts;
```

Complete scenario:

> Failed Test Class: OpportunityFeeCalculationTest
>
> Failed Class Methods: 1. test
>                         2. testOverFirstAUM

Class: OpportunityFeeCalculationTest

```
    @isTest
    public static void test()
    {        
        CoreDataTest.getRelationships();

        Test.startTest();


        Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c f1 = new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
            Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
            Tier_Description__c='First',
            Tier_AUM_Level__c=100000,
            Tier_Fee_Bps__c=33
        );

        Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c f2 = new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
            Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
            Tier_Description__c='Second',
            Tier_AUM_Level__c=300000,
            Tier_Fee_Bps__c=43
        );

        Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c f3 = new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,Tier_Description__c='Thereafter',Tier_Fee_Bps__c=33);
        insert f1;
        insert f2;
        insert f3;

        list<Opportunity> lista=new list<Opportunity>();
        lista.add(CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0]);

        OpportunityFeeCalculation_Core.calculateManagementFees(lista);       
    }  


    @isTest
    public static void testOverFirstAUM()
    {        
        CoreDataTest.getRelationships();

        list<Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c> scheds = new list<Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c> {
            new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
                Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
                Tier_Description__c='First',
                Tier_AUM_Level__c=300000,
                Tier_Fee_Bps__c=33
            )
            ,
            new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
                Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
                Tier_Description__c='Second',
                Tier_AUM_Level__c=100000,
                Tier_Fee_Bps__c=43
            )
            ,
            new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
                Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
                Tier_Description__c='Fourth',
                Tier_AUM_Level__c=900000,
                Tier_Fee_Bps__c=43
            )
            ,
            new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
                Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
                Tier_Description__c='Third',
                Tier_AUM_Level__c=100000,
                Tier_Fee_Bps__c=43
            )
            ,
            new Opportunity_Fee_Schedule__c(
                Opportunity__c=CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].id,
                Tier_Description__c='Thereafter',
                //Tier_AUM_Level__c=100,
                Tier_Fee_Bps__c=3
            )

        };        

        Test.startTest();        
        insert scheds;        

        CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0].Assets__c = 2500000;
        update CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0];

        list<Opportunity> lista=new list<Opportunity>{
            CoreDataTest.Opportunities[0]
        };        

        OpportunityFeeCalculation_Core.calculateManagementFees(lista);   
    }
}
```

---

> error: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
>
> Stack Trace: Class.UtilitiesContact.getEmployeeInfos: line 96, column
>   1 Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler_Core.beforeUpdate: line 232, column
>   1 Trigger.OpportunityBeforeUpdate_Core: line 5, column 1

---

Trigger.OpportunityBeforeUpdate_Core:

```
trigger OpportunityBeforeUpdate_Core on Opportunity (before update) {

    if (UtilitiesSObject.RunTrigger('OpportunityBeforeUpdate_Core'))
    {
Line 5: new OpportunityTriggerHandler_Core().beforeUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

---

Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler_Core.beforeUpdate

```
public void beforeUpdate(list<Opportunity> triggerNew,map<Id, Opportunity> triggerNewMap,map<Id, Opportunity> triggerOld)
{
    if (UtilitiesUser.UserContactInfo.Service_Account__c == false)
    {
        calculateManagementFees(triggerNew,triggerold);
        calculateProbability(triggerNew, triggerOld);

        map<string,boolean> keys = new map<string,boolean>();//lob+account
        set<id> lobs = new set<id>();
        set<id> companies = new set<id>();
        set<id> oppsAffected = new set<id>();
        list<id> ownerids = new list<id>();
        set<id> oppids = new set<id>();

        for (Opportunity o : triggerNewMap.values())
        {
            ownerids.add(o.ownerid);

            o.Restricted__c=o.Restricted_Formula__c;
            o.Platinum_Client_Group__c=o.Platinum_Client_Group_Formula__c;

            keys.put(o.LOB_Owner__c+'-'+o.Accountid,false);
            keys.put(o.LOB_Owner__c+'-'+o.Record_Keeper__c,false);
            keys.put(o.LOB_Owner__c+'-'+o.Consultant__c,false);
            lobs.add(o.LOB_Owner__c);
            companies.add(o.Accountid);
            companies.add(o.Record_Keeper__c);
            companies.add(o.Consultant__c);
            oppids.add(o.id);
        }   

        for(Company_LOB_Relationship__c clr:[
            select id,Company__c,LOB__c,Opt_Out__c 
            from Company_LOB_Relationship__c 
            where  LOB__c in :lobs
            AND Company__c IN :companies
        ])
        {
            string key = clr.LOB__c+'-'+clr.Company__c;
            if(keys.get(key)!=null)
            {
                keys.put(key,clr.Opt_Out__c);
            }        
        }

//Set Owner LOB
Line 232: map<Id, Contact> employeesByUser = UtilitiesContact.getEmployeeInfos(ownerids);
```

---

Class.UtilitiesContact.getEmployeeInfos: line 96, column 1

```
global static map<Id, Contact> getEmployeeInfos(list<Id> userIds)
    {
        map<Id, Contact> employeeContacts = new map<Id, Contact>();

Line 96: for (Contact c : [SELECT Name, User__c, User__r.IsActive, LOB__c, Email, Phone,LOB__r.Short_Name__c, LOB__r.Name FROM Contact WHERE User__c IN :userIds])
        {
            employeeContacts.put(c.User__c, c);
        }

        return employeeContacts;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you execute a test class or on a trigger or when? Some context would help to understand the situation.

Comment: the error could exist , for example, due to a trigger context in which getEmployeeInfos() is called more than 100 times. Could you provide some context informations?

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet does not contain enough information to figure out your issue. The SOQL 101 error is thrown when 101 SOQL statements are executed in a single request. It does not mean that the statement the error was thrown on was executed 101 times, it only means that it was the 101st SOQL statement. There could be another piece of code that ran before the code you have presented and that code executed 100 SOQL statements.

To debug this issue you should have a look in the log files. If you search for `SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN` you will find all the SOQL statements that have been called, there should be a repeating SOQL statement in there somewhere which is where the probably actually is.

Comment: {
                string key = clr.LOB__c+'-'+clr.Company__c;
                if(keys.get(key)!=null)
                {
                    keys.put(key,clr.Opt_Out__c);
                }        
            }
            
            //Set Owner LOB
 Line 232 -    map<Id, Contact> employeesByUser = UtilitiesContact.getEmployeeInfos(ownerids);

Comment: Class.UtilitiesContact.getEmployeeInfos: line 96, column 1

global static map<Id, Contact> getEmployeeInfos(list<Id> userIds)
    {
        map<Id, Contact> employeeContacts = new map<Id, Contact>();
        
Line 96:        for (Contact c : [SELECT Name, User__c, User__r.IsActive, LOB__c, Email, Phone,LOB__r.Short_Name__c, LOB__r.Name FROM Contact WHERE User__c IN :userIds])
        {
            employeeContacts.put(c.User__c, c);
        }
        
        return employeeContacts;
    }

Comment: If you have more information to add you your question then please click **edit** under your question and add the code there.

Comment: Thanks. I have update my question and provided complete details for your better understanding.

Comment: It is hard to follow your code or see a possible issue. As stated in my answer: _To debug this issue you should have a look in the log files. If you search for `SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN` you will find all the SOQL statements that have been called, there should be a repeating SOQL statement in there somewhere which is where the probably actually is._

Comment: Thanks man for your quick help, I will do as you suggested. I have highlighted the lines as per Stack trace in Code.

Comment: If you wish to debug your use of SOQL and any other limits there is a Salesforce class called Limits. (posted below)
You can then call in your could 
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Error, Limits.getQueries() )
and this will print out How many queries you have used at that point.
Put logging level to none for everything apart from apex Code to Error. Run process and see the numbers go up until you find the loop that coursed the issue

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code is not hitting the governor limit by itself.

At a guess, I would say that you're calling getEmployeeInfos() in a loop.

Please post the rest of your code to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Guess too late for answer but best guess here is your trigger Trigger.OpportunityBeforeUpdate_Core do not have recursion handling. Somewhere in your trigger you are updating opportunity which leads to fire this trigger again and again leading to 101 SOQL. Handle the recursion in your trigger.